# urllib2 downloads corrupt .jpg files

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I have a Python program in which I need to download .jpg files from the internet. I have a `while True:` loop that goes through the URLs I have and downloads a file from each one. Every 20 or so files, `urllib2` downloads a file that is half grey and `FPDF` refuses to make a PDF out of the downloaded files because of the corrupt ones.
Here's my code:

```
filename = ''.join(pageForFilename)
add_image_to_list()
file_ = open(filename, 'w')
file_.write(data)
file_.close()

time.sleep(0.5)
```

It may be useful to note that pageForFilename is page-001.jpg
I thought that maybe I wasn't allowing the script to fully download a file, so I added a `time.sleep(0.5)`, thinking that it would fix it.
python 2.7 MacOS Sierra

Comment: You think URLLib2 is corrupting the files. Of course you verified this by downloading such a corrupt file "manually" (through your browser, with curl, or with an FTP program, or any other way) and you got a correct file. Right?

Comment: Without any idea of what files you're downloading, it's pretty hard to debug what's going wrong. Maybe some of the files are actually JPEG2000 rather than JFIF and your JPG-to-PDF code can't handle those. Or maybe your code can't handle greyscale JPG even in JFIF. Maybe they're even mislabeled PNG or GIF files. Who knows?

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, I have tried manually getting the files from the URL and I get no issue with it.

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev And you verified that they are actually JPEG/JFIF files, and that your FPDF can handle them?

Comment: yes. If i take out the corrupt files, FPDF can process them and create a PDF. The urls from which i am downloading end in .jpg and my OS verifies that they are jpeg files

Comment: I didn't ask whether FPDF can process them if you take out the corrupt files, I asked whether FPDF can process the corrupt files if you download them manually. And the same is true for what the OS reports. (Not to mention that of course they're going to have `.jpg` extensions when you supply filenames like `page-001.jpg`, and your OS may be showing them as JPG just because of the extension; that doesn't mean they actually are in JPEG/JFIF format.)

Comment: @abarnert sorry, i misunderstood your question. FPDF can process them if i download them manually, but that's because they aren't corrupted files then.

Comment: the urls are telling me that the files are .jpg, because that's what they end in. Therefore, i am giving the files the .jpg extension

Comment: It would probably help if we can locally replicate your findings. Add a link to a file that consistently fails to download correctly.

Comment: You say the problem is in urllib, but you didn't include the code you used to download (and ev. to mangle the image). Download one of the corrupted image also with wget/curl, and check the differences,if headers are different, we need the setting you use to maipulate the image. If it is single bytes, check to understand if it is some encoding. If the size differ, check that you get the errors from urllib. You may need to retry download, if server close connection.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in (if you are in Windows):

```
file_ = open(filename, 'w')
```

you are writing a file as text.

Try with:

```
file_ = open(filename, 'wb')
```

do you force the file as binary.

Comment: I'm on mac, but `pageForFilename` is page-001.jpg. Surely if I were trying to save as a text file, every file saved would be corrupt? As it stands, it's one every 20 or so. I also get the same problem when trying this.

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev This probably isn't your problem, then—but you should still use binary mode when writing binary files. Using text files is the wrong thing to do, even if you sometimes get away with it.

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev Also, you haven't told us what `pageForFilename` means for your program, or why you think the filename should have any effect on things, and it's hard to guess why you think it's relevant.